# Metal performance debugging

Tags: ios, xcode, multithreading, metal, metalkit

I have a Metal application on iOS where I take video frames and pass each frame through a number of shaders, some are compute shaders applied in multiple passes and 4 of them are independent MTKViews which display computed textures (example, Histogram) along with video preview. Sometimes (but not always) on older hardware such as iPhone 6s, I notice the app has become too sluggish with frame rate dropping to 1 or 2 frames per second. Please let me know how to debug which Metal shaders are clogging the GPU/GPU and how do I optimize the performance of Metal related code.

Comment: Does the phone feel particularly hot when the frame rate drops to 1 or 2 FPS?

Comment: No, nothing like that. Sometimes the frame rate returns to normal after 20 seconds or so.

Comment: Can you point me to list of debugging & profiling tools for Metal and any articles/videos that show how to use them?

Comment: Check out the Metal-related videos from last year's WWDC. They're on the Apple website.

Comment: I checked them, but looks like you need to look at other videos before you could understand them fully. I am unable to find other videos.

Comment: A quick note on this, you will not be able to run compute shaders on the A7 and be able to process video fast enough to keep up with full screen 30 FPS video. Even fragment shaders can be too slow on the A7, though A8 and newer GPU are fast enough to run video compute workloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Run your application in Xcode.
2. Select Debug -> Capture GPU frame
3. Select Issue Navigator from the left toolbar
4. Select Runtime
5. Fix the listed issues, at least "high" priority.
6. You can also see where the performance is being spent by looking at `drawPrimitives` etc. times in the debug navigator on the left.

To view a shader's performance details, select the draw or dispatch call from the event list on the left. There's a "performance" section.

Comment: @DeepakSharma I updated my answer for displaying more performance info.

Comment: Where exactly I find "performance" section? I don't see compute command encoder anywhere in the left pane. Only Render commands!

Comment: I can see it on iOS 11 devices but not iOS 10 :(

Comment: I think it's got to do with execution of compute shader at the time of GPU frame capture!